# background picture alignment

Tags: php, css

my background picture alignment seem to be not right. The bottom part seems to be cut off. how do i get the background picture align to the middle.

```
body {
background-image: url('<?php echo $backgroundpic;?>');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
background-attachment:fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is add background-size and set it to cover

```
    body {
background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWFou.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;//ANSWER
background-attachment:fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

hope that could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Thank you.. just one more question, the background picture seems to be too big.. how do i adjust it to fit the browser screen ?

Comment: background-size: cover should take care of that. Do you have a live URL that you can share?

Comment: no live url ... let me check if my background picture might be the issue or if i can crop my picture